# pySerial program doesn't read serial correctly

Tags: python, windows, serial-port, arduino, pyserial

I have a problem using pySerial, and I don´t know from where to start looking for.
I have a 64 bits Windows Seven OS, with Python 2.7.5 (32 bits), and pySerial and Arduino (Arduino working correctly) already installed.

My Arduino code is the following:

```
// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {                
  // initialize the serial in 19200 baud rate
  Serial.begin(19200);     
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
  Serial.print("hello");
}
```

(Arduino conected in COM8, when using Serial Monitor I can see it saluting)

And my PySerial code looks like this:

```
import serial
import time

arduino = serial.Serial("COM8", 19200)
time.sleep(2)  

while True:
    print arduino.readline()
```

When I start this script, the program runs, but I can´t see the serial output (I think the configuration in the Python script is OK because if something - e.g. the port - is wrong, it crashes).

I don´t know what to do to find a solution.
Can you help me?

Comment: I think pySerial works fine ... this falls under operator error ...

Comment: Yes, I think so. But I don't know from where to start looking for an answer :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try using `println` instead of `print` on the Arduino/C side, and/or set a timeout for the serial read on the Python side.

Since `serial.readline()` waits for a `\n`, and you never send one using print, the serial read will just wait for a timeout.  (But it's a bit more complicated than this, and it's worth reading the [docs](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#readline) on readline and EOL.)

If this doesn't work, at least switch `readline` to just `read` and print out each character you may (or may not) be reading, but don't make it more complicated by waiting for the `\n` that `readline` requires.

From the demo [docs](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#readline):
Be carefully when using readline(). Do specify a timeout when opening the serial port otherwise it could block forever if no newline character is received. Also note that readlines() only works with a timeout. readlines() depends on having a timeout and interprets that as EOF (end of file). It raises an exception if the port is not opened correctly.

Comment: Thanks in advance for the help. I used another Arduino code (already verified) but I could not get the expected results either. I think something is wrong in my system, but I can´t find where...